# Rails 3.1: Sass Import from Lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

I've got a bunch of 'bootstrap' sass files I'd like to stick in my applications `/lib` directory, following the new conventions of the asset pipeline.

However, I need to import these into my `application.css.scss` rather than requiring them, as I would like to share some color variables etc. throughout the app. I have not been able to figure out a way to get `@import` to grab a `.scss` file from `/lib/assets/stylesheets`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@import` *should* look for any `.css.scss` files located in your assets load path, be it in `app/assets/stylesheets`, `lib/assets/stylesheets`, `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, or any additional paths added by gems, so it's odd that you're getting an error.

Note you do not need to pass a folder name when using `@import` unless the file is in a subdirectory of `assets/stylesheets` - `sass-rails` will look through every folder on your load path and see if the resource exists relative to those folders.

To ensure that `lib/assets/stylesheets` is in your assets load path (which it should be, since it's a default option) crack open a Rails prompt and type `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`. As an example, here's the result for one of my applications:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :012 > Rails.application.config.assets.paths
 => ["/Users/tom/ruby/qa/app/assets/images",
 "/Users/tom/ruby/qa/app/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/tom/ruby/qa/app/assets/stylesheets", 
 "/Users/tom/ruby/qa/lib/assets/stylesheets",
 "/Users/tom/ruby/qa/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/tom/ruby/qa/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
 "/Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts",
 "/Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bootstrap-sass-1.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts", 
 "/Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bootstrap-sass-1.4.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets"]
```

It's also worth ensuring that `sass-rails` is up to date and running the latest version, since I believe early versions had limit support in terms of cross-folder `@import`.

<sup>*N.B:* I also believe that convention suggests files such as Bootstrap or jQuery should go in your `vendor/assets` folder rather than `lib/assets`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it working. I must have just had a typo somewhere. FWIW the bootstrap file in question is my own custom creation that I use to start out any new apps, so to me that seems like "lib" (shared among my own apps) rather than "vendor" (public distributions).

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense, I just joined the dots between your comment on my answer yesterday and your question now and figured you were using some version of Twitter's Bootstrap, in that case, disregard my footnote, `lib` is definitely the right place

Comment: Oh... :) Actually the main reason for my comment on your answer was I was very happy to find an example of a bootstrap being made into a gem utilizing the asset pipeline. I'd like to extract my custom bootstrap into a gem someday and yours is a great reference on how to do that. For now just moving it to lib is a nice cleanup. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, and it was because i forgot restart server after add files to lib directory.